# bash or Ksh quotes and command exec

Tags: bash, shell-script, ksh

while creating a script I am facing currently a "strange" issue that so far I am unable to fix.

```
typeset -r SERVICE=\"ldap://localhost:10389\ ldaps://solsrv02.internal.vbox:10689\ ldaps://solsrv02.prod.internal.vbox:10689\"
SLAPD="/usr/lib/slapd -u ${LDAPUSR} -g ${LDAPGRP} -h ${SERVICE} -F ${CONF_DIR}"
```

Currently the variable assignment is like above and when I echo the SLAPD it works like a charm. but when I execute the command :
Echo output

```
 /usr/lib/slapd -u openldap -g openldap -h "ldap://localhost:10389 ldaps://solsrv02.internal.vbox:10689 ldaps://solsrv02.prod.internal.vbox:10689" -F /etc/openldap/standalone
```

Debug output

```
+ [[ ! -d /var/openldap/run ]]
+ /bin/rm -f /var/openldap/run/slapd.pid
+ /usr/lib/slapd -u openldap -g openldap -h '"ldap://localhost:10389' ldaps://solsrv02.internal.vbox:10689 'ldaps://solsrv02.prod.internal.vbox:10689"' -F /etc/openldap/standalone
```

So, my issue now, is that openldap command line forces me to have -h "URLs" and adding then to the variable it takes the variable as 3 parameters instead of a single as I wish.

I have tried to backspace the quotes but it expands to 3 single quotes.
If I just copy the output of echo and paste it on the script it works. but this has the downside that I cannot customize using variables.

all the variables have been set with `typeset -r`

**UPDATE 1**

Based on the given answer by cas, I updated my code but still facing the same issue:

```
   #!/usr/bin/bash
echo $SHELL
typeset -r SLAPD=/usr/lib/slapd
typeset -r LDAPUSR=openldap
typeset -r LDAPGRP=openldap
typeset -r VARRUNDIR=/var/openldap/run
typeset -r PIDFILE=${VARRUNDIR}/slapd.pid
typeset -r CONF_DIR=/etc/openldap/standalone
typeset -r SERVICE=(ldap://localhost:10389 ldaps://solsrv02.internal.vbox:10689 ldaps://solsrv02.prod.internal.vbox:10689)
SLAPARGS=" -u ${LDAPUSR}"
SLAPARGS+=" -g ${LDAPGRP}"
SLAPARGS+=" -F ${CONF_DIR}"
SLAPARGS+=" -h "
SIZE=${#SERVICE[@]}

#for i in {1..${#SERVICE[@]}$}; do
SLAPARGS+="'"
for ((i=0;i<$SIZE;i=$i+1)); do
        SLAPARGS+="${SERVICE[$i]} "
done
SLAPARGS+="'"
[[ ! -d ${CONF_DIR} ]] && exit $SMF_EXIT_ERR_CONFIG

echo "$SLAPD $SLAPARGS"
set -x
$SLAPD $SLAPARGS 2>&1
```

the output is this:

```
/usr/bin/bash
/usr/lib/slapd  -u openldap -g openldap -F /etc/openldap/standalone -h 'ldap://localhost:10389 ldaps://solsrv02.internal.vbox:10689 ldaps://solsrv02.prod.internal.vbox:10689 '
+ [[ ! -d /var/openldap/run ]]
+ /bin/rm -f /var/openldap/run/slapd.pid
+ /usr/lib/slapd -u openldap -g openldap -F /etc/openldap/standalone -h ''\''ldap://localhost:10389' ldaps://solsrv02.internal.vbox:10689 ldaps://solsrv02.prod.internal.vbox:10689 ''\'''
```

Bash version is 4.1.17

Comment: 1. why do you need `SERVICE` to be read-only? 2. don't use `\"` when defining `SERVICE`, use single-quotes instead.  3. use double-quotes around `$SERVICE` when you use it on the slapd command line.

Comment: @cas thank you for the input and answer, but still it does not solve my problem. when using echo the output is just fine. executing the command is when I get added quotes / double quotes.

Comment: not sure why you're creating SERVICE as an array and then have a loop appending elements from it to $SLAPARGS...you seem to be defeating the purpose.   simpler to just add it to $SLAPARGS with `SLAPARGS+="$SLAPARGS -h '$SERVICE[@]}'"` - remember `slapd`'s `-h` option requires a single string as an arg.  BTW, `set -x` will try to print quoted strings in a format that can be copy-pasted, which may not be exactly the same as what was executed....and the correct way to embed a single-quote inside single quotes is `'\''`

Comment: i still don't get why you're defining all those variables as read-only?  is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: BTW, the method of building up SLAPARGS that i outlined in my answer is exactly the same as i use to build up and use ARGS variables for my `rsync` backup scripts and my `debmirror` wrapper script, and in many other scripts.  the method works exactly as i want/expect it to in all those scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SLAPD='/usr/bin/slapd'

SERVICE='ldap://localhost:10389 ldaps://solsrv02.internal.vbox:10689  ldaps://solsrv02.prod.internal.vbox:10689'

SLAPDARGS="-u '${LDAPUSR}'"
SLAPDARGS+=" -g '${LDAPGRP}'"
SLAPDARGS+=" -h '${SERVICE}'"
SLAPDARGS+=" -F '${CONFDIR}'"

$SLAPD $SLAPDARGS
```

Just so you can see what that does (when run after `$LDAPUSR`, `$LDAPGRP`, and `$CONFDIR` have been appropriately defined):

```
$ echo $SLAPD $SLAPDARGS 
/usr/bin/slapd -u 'ldap' -g 'ldap' -h 'ldap://localhost:10389 ldaps://solsrv02.internal.vbox:10689 ldaps://solsrv02.prod.internal.vbox:10689' -F '/etc/ldap'
```

If your shell doesn't support `+=`, use something like this instead:

```
SLAPDARGS="-u '${LDAPUSR}'"
SLAPDARGS="${SLAPDARGS} -g '${LDAPGRP}'"
SLAPDARGS="${SLAPDARGS} -h '${SERVICE}'"
SLAPDARGS="${SLAPDARGS} -F '${CONFDIR}'"
```

The key is to use single-quotes when you DON'T want interpolation and glob expansion etc, and either no quotes or double-quotes when you do want them.  For example, you DON'T wany any quotes around `$SLAPDARGS` when you're using it on the command-line that runs `$SLAPD`, otherwise they will be passed as a single argument to `slapd`.

Another alternative is to use an array for SLAPDARGS instead of a simple string.

BTW, if you like to keep script line lengths below 80 columns, `$SERVICE` can be built up incrementally the same way `$SLAPDARGS` was - and could also be defined as an array rather than a simple string.